# When trying to delete a Request, receive a (#200) The entity backed by id V cannot be seen by the current viewer

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm trying to delete notification requests, per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting

by doing this:

```
app_token = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(FB_APP_ID,FB_SECRET).get_app_access_token
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(app_token)
graph.delete_object("#{request_id}_#{user_id}")
```

The Koala gem is sending:
  request: !ruby/struct:VCR::Request
    method: :post
    uri: https://graph.facebook.com:443/313178335366125_1799948928
    body: access_token=[APP_TOKEN]&method=delete
    headers:
      content-type:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

which seems to be what I want.  But it is failing with:
      - ! 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) The entity backed
        by id 313178335366125 cannot be seen by the current viewer (EntID: 313178335366125)"'

I'm at a bit of a loss here.  It seems realize that I'm providing the id of a request, because it was smart enough to chop the underscore and userid from the end of the request.  But if that's the case, why the error?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Was this answer the correct one, or was there another solution to your problem?  I'm looking for info on using koala to delete app_requests and google took me here :)

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the app request doesn't exist. You have probably deleted it earlier. It may take some time before old requests are hidden in the Facebook GUI, so if you click/delete an old request that has already been deleted you will get the error message.

[Lazerwire](http://www.lazerwire.com)